# How to Get the currently logged on user name

Tags: c#, .net

I am building a small intranet app in which I need to display the user name of the person who opens the webpage.

I tries with:

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();
```

But this always displays my user name on the webpage.

Comment: Have you tried with another user apart from yourself?

Comment: Yes I tried from another user

Comment: AFAIK this only works with impersonation turned on and setup correctly. WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString(); could show the username that 'started' the webhost instead of the user visiting the website. Maybe some scheme based on mac addres/ipadres/machine name would be handier and would work with non Iexplore browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please see [THIS](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/How_to_NT_User_Name.aspx) - basicaly you need to enable `Integrated windows authentication` and the use one of the following:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal p = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal as System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal;    
string strName = p.Identity.Name;
```

or

```
string strName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
```

or

```
string strName = Request.ServerVariables["AUTH_USER"]; //Finding with name    
string strName = Request.ServerVariables[5]; //Finding with index
```

All 3 cases should retrun a string containing `DomainName\WinNTLoggedUserName`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
Page.User.Identity.Name
```

**P.S:** Don't forget to check entities whether they were null first.

Comment: or in MVC: HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
 Label1.Text = User.Identity.Name;
else
 Label1.Text = "No user identity available.";
```

look at the following article [Forms Authentication in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx)

Comment: Always getting No user Identity available

Comment: What type of authentication are you use?

Comment: Then you have a broken login system. Do you use `FormsAuthentication`?

Comment: @LordCover , I am using Windows Authentication. Could you help me on how to enable FormsAuthentication

Comment: look at the article that I put link above in answer

Answer (score 0):

See http://forums.asp.net/t/1102996.aspx/1. I think the reason that you see your own name is that the web app is running under your credentials.

So use `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` instead and make sure that you have enabled [Forms authentication](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240) in web.config